# Merging release to master after a patch release git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge, release

We recently migrated from svn to git. We currently have a release branch and a master branch. We merge release to master on the day of the release and tag it.

Now if we were to do a patch release. Which is create a branch off master as a hotfix branch and merge it to master, then create a new tag and release from there. Then we also merge that hotfix back into release so release has all of the changes in production while QA are testing it.

Then the issue comes in when we have to merge the release branch back into master.

1) We can't do a fast forward release as the master has diverged

2) If we do a normal merge even will it be safe (this will also add a merge commit) will that code be duplicated sometimes, what will happen we are not sure

3) We could rebase release from master, but this is a common public branch (would mess up developers local branch?) and rebasing release would be dangerous as well?
If we don't rebase ideally we won't have a clean history on master branch with tag points in all releases either

How do you do a release and usually handle this

Comment: "We merge release to master on the day of the release" That reads as if you did `git checkout master; git merge release` which seems backwards.

Comment: Merge `release` into `master`. `master` has 'diverged', but it is the same commit that is also in `release`, so there should be no conflicts. What you describe is similar to the [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) strategy, which is very commonly used. When using git flow there is a `development` branch (similar to your `release` branch). Hotfixes that are branched from `master` are merged with both `master` and `development`. `development` can later be merged into `master` again (via the `release` branch in the case of git flow).

Answer (score 0):

> Then we also merge that `hotfix` back into `release`
>
> We can't do a fast forward `release` as the `master` has diverged

One way to improve that workflow and avoid the diverge situation would be to add one more merge, just after the `hotfix` merge:

```
git checkout relase
git merge -s ours master
```

That way, you record that `release` and `master` are "merged".

That will allow you, later, to make a fast-forward merge from `release` to `master`.

Comment: Before I add any further comments, could you elaborate bit on "--ours"? I also checked the git docs for merge and there seem to be two "ours" listed.

Comment: @MilindaD ours is a merge strategy enabling to record a merge without changing *anything* on the destination branch. That will allow you to create a common ancestor which will make a future fast-forward merge possible.

Comment: So we merge hotfix to both master and release, afterwards do an "ours" merge to state we merged this. correct? Also since we merge hotfix back to release, even if there is a conflict when we do an "ours" merge later on we still can do a fast forward merge. correct? Also just to clarify is this what you do at your workplace (and in other organizations)?

Comment: @MilindaD yes, merge master to  release with ours strategy: there won't be any conflict as that merge does not merge anything (it keep ours: the destination branch).

Comment: I tried this out, I get the following error `git merge --ours testmaster
error: unknown option 'ours'`, can you provide the exact syntax? my release branch is testrelease which is the branc I am in when running the ours merge command then

Comment: @MilindaD sorry, `git merge -s ours master`